# I created scala a live template, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm confused why my live template is not working.

I clicked on the + sign and created a new live template for Scala.

```
Abbreviation:  slick-update
Template text:
$table$.filter(_.id === $model$.id).update($model$).flatMap(whenSucceeded($model$))
```

I clicked ok.

Now in my .scala file, if I type cmd-j or I type 'scala-update' I do not see my new live template name appear anywhere.

Why isn't it working?  Do I have to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to restart.

When creating a live template, IDEA warns you that you need to define contexts that template can be used in.

Below the `Template text` field, click `Define`, then select

`Scala > Code`

and save the changes.

That should make your template work.